# What do you mean by instance in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having tough time understanding the meaning of Instance properties

For example in Firefox ES6 Class document it says 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

**Instance properties**

Instance properties must be defined inside of class methods

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {    
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

I just see this as a class with constructor, so what do they mean by instance properties?

Comment: Do you understand what an "instance" is…?

Comment: https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/instance // These properties are individual for each individual instance of your class that you create. When you have a class `person`, then you want the `name` property of that to hold a different value for each person _instance_ you create … Opposed to that would be a _static_ property, one that all instances share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance properties there are `height` and `width`:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {    
    this.height = height;
//  -----^^^^^^
    this.width = width;
//  -----^^^^^
  }
}
```

An "instance" is an object. One tends to use "instance" in relation to code using class-like syntax, but it just means object (though often the implication is "object of a particular class").

Contrast with "static" or "class" properties:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {    
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
Rectangle.FOUR_BY_FOUR = new Rectangle(4,4);
```

There, `FOUR_BY_FOUR` is a "class/static" property. Or using the syntax proposed by the [static class features proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features/) (currently Stage 3):

```
class Rectangle {
  static FOUR_BY_FOUR = new Rectangle(4,4);

  constructor(height, width) {    
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That means each instance of a `Rectangle` will have the properties `height` and `width`.

Later, they show how to create an instance.

```
const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);
```

Here, `square` is an instance of a `Rectangle` whose `height` and `width` properties are both initialized to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can picture `class` as a blueprint or modelling. Using the `class` that you've defined in your question for explanation

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {    
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

We have a class named `Rectangle` as a "blueprint" or design. Now we can create many individual `instance`/`object` by defining their own instance properties, base on this "blueprint"/`Rectangle`

```
let bigRectangle = new Rectangle(300,300);
let smallRectangle = new Rectangle(50,50);
```